# How to change File/Product version of DLLs in TeamCity using AssemblyInfo Patcher produced from a .net solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, continuous-integration, teamcity, .net-core-2.1

**There are multiple c# class library (DotNet Core 2.1) projects and User Interface (WPF project) in my solution.**

Let say a class library project properties have Assembly version 2019.1.15341.0:

[image: Project 1 has Assembly version 2019.1.15341.0]

Also, the same Assembly version is assigned to the user interface (WPF application):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2019.1.15341.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("2019.1.15341.0")]
```

**In TeamCity, I have configured AssemblyInfo Patcher:**

[image: TeamCity AssemblyInfo Patcher]

**I build the complete solution using TeamCity and the builds were successful:**

[image: Build Successful in TeamCity]

**Now let's see the property of artifacts produced after Building the complete solution:**

**1. Project 1 (Class library, DLL properties):**

[image: project1.dll]

**2. UserInterface (WPF project):**

[image: USER interface exe]

**I see that the `UserInterface.exe's Version` has been changed by TeamCity according to it's `build counter` and `build vcs number`, but Why the `DLL's version` is not changed? Am I missing any steps? or anything else?**

> Any information I am missing please inform.

The properties of EXEs seems fine as expected. The main concern is on the DLLs: It's property is not getting changed.

Comment: Expected results for Project1.dll was: `Product Version: 2019.1.25801`

Comment: Note: The class library project is in `.net core 2.1`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned it is a `.Net Core` project, so it may not be having an `AssemblyInfo.cs` where Assembly properties are defined.

So go to Build Features in TeamCity, and add a Build Feature.

1. Select: File content replacer
2. (optional) Click on Load Template and search or type for Version under **.Net Core**

[image: Adding File content replacer as Build Feature]

3. You can use a regular expression of your own like: `<Version>\S*<\/Version>` or use template regex: `(<(Version)\s*>).*(<\/\s*\2\s*>)`

[image: Replace with:]

I have used Replace With: `<Version>%MAJOR%.%MINOR%.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%</Version>` so that `<version>` and `</version>` tags don't get deleted as per my regex. It all depends on your regex what you need to replace.

Similarly, I have added other required parameters: [image: other required parameters]

**Pros:**
After building the project I can see the expected results in properties.

**Cons:**
Searches and Replaces the files multiple times and not once (the number of Build features, the same number of time it will be executed, and the same number of time it will be reverted!)

Comment: Just tried: replace all versions at once: the regex `Version>\d*.\d*.\d*.\d*<` and replace with Version>%MAJOR%.%MINOR%.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%<

Comment: There's a bug in the above comment code, so use: the regex `20\d*[.]\d\d*[.]\d*[.]*\d*` and %MAJOR%.%MINOR%.%build.counter%.%build.vcs.number%

Comment: Worth noting that this solution, which uses VCS number for the "revision" digit, will fail if the VCS number is greater than 65535.  I'd suggest just following the Microsoft convention of keeping "revision" at zero until a hotfix is released.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jjameson/2009/04/03/best-practices-for-net-assembly-versioning/

Answer (score 2):

According to the [TeamCity AssemblyInfo patcher docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/AssemblyInfo+Patcher):

> ...after this build feature is configured, it will run before the first build step. TeamCity will first perform replacement in the files found in the build checkout directory and then run your build.

However, the values you have on the Package tab of the DLL projects' settings (your first screenshot) are applied during the build process itself, that is when MSBuild processes your projects. I suspect the values set by TeamCity Assembly patcher are replaced back to defaults here.

Comment: ya might be. But the same values are set to WPF project also. I manually tried to find out: I saw that TeamCity searches for `AssemblyInfo.cs` and modifies the build number there, and in case of class library project the AssemblyInfo.cs is not present, Assembly information is stored in csproj.

Comment: @GourGopal, right, if there's no AssemblyInfo file, the patcher won't work.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to modify the .csproj file in TeamCity before build?

Comment: There's [File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/File+Content+Replacer), which is actually recommended for some more complex scenarios. Seems like [this section](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/File+Content+Replacer#FileContentReplacer-.NetCorecsprojtemplates) describes your case.

Comment: I will try. Thanks